# Performance log not capturing in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working on .net core 3.1 web api where I want to capture performance for every request made to api. Following is the code I have done that does not log anything in Application Insights Performance but when I explicitly registered the middleware using

```
    var telemetryClient = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();
    app.UseApplicationInsightsMiddleware<ApplicationInsightsMiddleware>(telemetryClient);
```

performance logs are getting captured.

As per couple of articles in internet, by just doing below settings performance log can be captured but its not working. Please suggest what I am doing wrong?

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },  
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/",
  },
  "MaxFileSize": 25,
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "LoggingConfiguration": {
    "Log4Net": "log4net.config",
    "ApplicationInsights": "xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx",
    "ApplicationInsightsLiveMetricsApiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Configuration config = Configuration.GetSection("LoggingConfiguration").Get<Configuration>();

        services.AddTransfastLogger((log4Net_Options) =>
        {
            log4Net_Options.ConfriguationFileName = config.Log4Net;
        }, (applicationInsightsOptions) =>
        {
            applicationInsightsOptions.InstrumentationKey = config.ApplicationInsights;
            applicationInsightsOptions.ConnectionString = string.Empty;
            applicationInsightsOptions.LiveMetricsAuthenticationApiKey = config.ApplicationInsightsLiveMetricsApiKey;
        });
        
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    }
```

**WeatherForecastController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {

        var iteracion = 4;

        _logger.LogDebug($"Debug {iteracion}");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Information {iteracion}");
        _logger.LogWarning($"Warning {iteracion}");
        _logger.LogError($"Error {iteracion}");
        _logger.LogCritical($"Critical {iteracion}");

        try
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        }

        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing the traces atleast in local?

Comment: @Harshitha, Aer you referring log4net file based logs? yes its there in local

Comment: Ok..so you want to check the basic logs only with configuration (application insights) settings?

Comment: The issue seems to be with your configuration file.Will check from my end and let you know.

Comment: You have set configuration in `appsettings.Development.json`.For the app to work after deploying the configuration has to be set in `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Production.json` file.

Comment: @Harshitha, settings are perfect in appsettings.Development.json, as I mentioned in my post Performance are been captured when I explicitly register -> var telemetryClient = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();
    app.UseApplicationInsightsMiddleware<ApplicationInsightsMiddleware>(telemetryClient);  without this setting its not been captured ..

Comment: You are running the app locally or from the deployed url ?

Comment: I tried with both localhost and also deployed on server, its working only with var telemetryClient = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();
    app.UseApplicationInsightsMiddleware<ApplicationInsightsMiddleware>(telemetryClient);

Comment: Ok will try from my end with cofiguration and without code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256093/discussion-between-harshitha-and-neeraj-kumar-gupta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to log Traces and see the same in Performance section.

I am using VS 2022 17.8.0 version.

Configured Application Insights from the `Connected Services`.

[image]

- As mentioned, I haven't added any middleware related to the Telemetry.
- My `Startup.cs` file has only the below line of code to log Application Insights Telemetry.

```cs
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);
```

***OR***

```cs
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

- I have configured the same settings as yours in  `appsettings.Development.json` file.
- I have tried with both latest `2.21.0` and `2.15.0` older versions of  `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`
  package.

Make sure you are executing the Controller Action Method

```cs
https://localhost:portno./weatherforecast
```

***Output:***
[image]

- Check under the `Server`,   `Operations` tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Harshitha. this is only a part I haven't done 'Configured Application Insights from the Connected Services.' let me do this as well

Comment: By configuring Application Insights as mentioned above, the default logs/traces/ requests will be logged without adding any code.

Comment: Required packages will be installed automatically.

Comment: Its start working after downgrading the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore first to 2.15.0 then upgraded to 2.21.0, when I created the sample application I directly selected the 2.21.0, this is strange.

Comment: Ok..Now you are able to see the performance traces..